# Auto email confirmation of their order

Tags: order-status, order-email

When a customer places an order through the website is there a way to make it so they automatically get sent an email confirmation of their order?

At the moment I have to manually send them through Magento. Is there a way to make this an automatic process?

Thanks

Comment: you need to setup the cronjob, for Magento, after that Magento will send the emails automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass sending email via cron , 
this might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450413/magento-1-9-1-0-order-confirmation-emails-not-sending

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can configure order email in magento admin. please refer this link.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-sales-email-magento-2.html